# aws delete reports group history

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-codebuild

I'm attempting to use the AWS CLI to delete the history of a codebuild reports-group. (Context: It was muddied when we were initially setting up these reports.)

I notice that it's possible to just delete the entire reports-group, but I only want to clear the history. Is there an easy way to delete the history without destroying the entire reports-group?

The man page gives options for deleting an individual report, but there are possibly 500+, and I've no idea how nor the intent to run that command that many times.

My man page diving so far has landed me here:

```
aws codebuild delete-reports help
```

So far I have also found `batch-delete-builds`, but there's no `batch-delete-reports` that I can tell. Should I just delete the reports-group or is there a command that just isn't named as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such api, you can delete the report group. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codebuild/delete-report-group.html